# How to modify java editor's context menu per perspective?

Tags: java, eclipse, contextmenu

The context menu is cluttered with items I will never use when working on a particular group of projects.

For example, I have aspectj installed. But most of my projects do not deal with aspectj. So I wish to create a perspective where aspectj items are not displayed.

I should not have to hack into each respective plug-in to do that.

I could configure the perspective to restrict the menu and toolbar items being displayed.

Therefore, common sense leads me to believe that I should be able to configure my perspective to reduce the number of items on the editor context popup menu. If there is a way, could you please let me know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options you can do. First, you can select the Customize Perspective... option from the Window menu, and disable Menu/Toolbar contributions.

And to disable some views in a permanently saveable way (e.g. it survives the closing of the perspective) you can save your current state into a new perspective using the Save Perspective... option from the Window menu.